# How to stop react from lagging on re-render?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use custom marquee , but every time **state** updates, my component App re-renders, and this cause some lagging in animation in marquee.I tried to `shouldComponentUpdate()` life cycle but this didn't help because this could make re-render process is slow specially if i have too many state update every 3 to 5 seconds, and i tried looking for only one state to change but this didn't help also , because this prevent component from re-render if other **state** changed. Those are the approaches i tried to do

***1.*** using `shouldComponentUpdate`

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if(this.state.count !== nextState.count){
    return false
  }
  return true;
}
```

this didn't work due to there's a lot of **state** changes every 5 seconds

***2.*** Tried using some custom css

to prevent it from lagging using

```
will-change: transform
```

all of the above didn't work, so i came here with my question so that can someone help me with lagging problems in animation

**NOTE** the marquee lib i used in child component, not the parent (App.js) and the lagging stopped when i commented the HTTP request that updates the state in the parent.

so that's why i came with the conclusion of the cause of lagging happens when component re-renders.
The problem that i'm looking for isn't in the code, that's why i didn't put all of my code here and ask to be fixed, i asked the question, so that someone can help me understand the **problem of animation lags on re-render**

**NOTE2** about state has to many updates , what i mean by that, i have

```
this.state = {
  count: 0,
  data: [],
  comments: [],
  posts: [],
  notifications: [],
}
```

**And these states are constantly updates every 5 seconds using HTTP request
in parent component**

**NOTE3** I use HTTP request on `componentDidMount()` and with `this.interval` this code happens in App.js (parent)

```
componentDidMount(){
  this._isMounted = true
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
   fetch('http://localhost:3000/getnotifications')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      notifications: response
    })
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))

   // here also HTTP request for the rest of state

  }, 5000)
}

componentWillUnmount(){
 this._isMounted = false
 clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

I've updated my question to answer some comments bellow

Comment: You're probably encountering issues that `state management` frameworks use to resolve. You'll maybe need to batch actions that triggers re-renders in order to limit too much renders. See `mobx` or `redux`.

Comment: @samb102 i know lots can be solved when it comes to state management  by using redux ,but i was asking about reactjs to solve this issue using reactjs

Comment: You don't need to opt-in to a state management library when you can simply `debounce` your events that trigger a state update.

Comment: @Andrei can you explain more , sorry i don't follow

Comment: The question doesn't explain why there are many state updates. *this didn't work due to there's a lot of state changes every 5 seconds* - what are these changes, so shouldComponentUpdate doesn't help?

Comment: The animation lags because it's being triggered every time the component renders. One solution is to simply stop having the component re-render that fast.

If you're using state to save text you've typed (for example), you can take that logic and put it in a component dedicated to input, that doesn't update the state of the component with the animation on every keystroke, but only once the user is done typing or presses "Enter" or something like this.

Comment: @Andrei theses updates happens in parent component, so can you explain how to isolate the state with dedicated component and then pass the props to the parent component

Comment: You have several options. You can use `React.memo` to only re-render a component if the props it received have changed. Or you could change your component tree so the component with animations isn't directly nested in one that continuously re-renders.

Comment: the parent component is **continuously re-renders.**

Comment: If none of the above are an option, and the component that animates actually receives the props that cause the re-render, you have the option to `debounce` the input source that causes the refreshes. See [here](http://demo.nimius.net/debounce_throttle/) for a visual explanation of what debouncing does. Read [this post](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf) on how to do debouncing in JS.